# htaccess redirect condition to redirect old URL to new URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Previously, I have a redirect rule

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(---[^/]+)/?$ pc.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L,NC,QSA,NE]
```

1) This gives an output: http://me.com/i-am-here---125/

Now, I want it to change to something better and more SEO friendly. I am using the below rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ pc.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

2) This gives an output: http://me.com/125/i-am-here/

**My question**: How do I redirect all the old URL (1) to the new URL (2) format?

Comment: One question: since you already use rewriting rules doing something similar to what you ask here.... is there a specific reason why you don't want to write that additional rule yourself? Especially since you  are omnipotent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have this redirect rule before your existing rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)---([^/]+)/?$ /$2/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ pc.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(---[^/]+)/?$ $2/$1/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I am left with "---" in the URL which I have to eliminate to get just the ID. Any clues?